# Embedding Excel file with iFrame not working correctly

Tags: html, excel, iframe, embed, onedrive

I am using iframe to embed an Excel file into a HTM page using the [Microsoft OneDrive embed function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-onedrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081), and it will display the excel file, but it doesn't embed it, it makes the entire page the excel file.

So it takes over the entire page, I lose the sidebar and toolbar of my site that has the navigation.

I tried containing it within a div and apply class styles to both the div and the iframe, which is what I used for my PDFs that I embed that work fine, but it still did not restrict the excel file to an embedded window.

This is what I am using for the excel iframe:

```
<body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=7CDAFECF25AB92FC%21110&authkey=%21AGaGmMnPaiFZ0Ew&em=2">
        </iframe>
 </body>
```

And this is what I use for my PDF iframe:

```
<body>
    <div class="container"><iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="PS-U-A150FUI.pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Here are images to better show the issue, first image is a PDF correctly imbedded within the webpage.
Second is the excel doc that has overtaken the webpage.

[PDF Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDa4C.png)
[Excel Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfD5j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=7CDAFECF25AB92FC%21110&authkey=%21AGaGmMnPaiFZ0Ew&em=2">
</iframe>
```

You have used 100% width and 100% width in your HTML. So the iframe takes up the complete screen.

Take an example: you need the frame to be 500px wide and 700px long, then you could have used the `width=“500px”`
and the `height=“700px”` attributes in your iframe or used the following css:

```
 iframe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

**What basically I want to say is, that you should use smaller pixel-values/percentages for the iframe.**

Comment: That just set it to take over the webpage at 500x700.

I used % as it is a html page contained within a larger overarching responsive html5 layout.

So it would be 100% x 100% of the space available in the responsive area, but again, it still overwrote the entirety of the webpage and replaced it with the excel frame, and did not embed it into the page.

Comment: That’s exactly what I want to explain. If you use 100% as the width as well as the height, the iframe covers the entire page. If you use smaller pixel-values or smaller percentages for the height and width. I ain’t telling you not to use percentages, but am just saying, use smaller values.

Comment: I updated my post when I replied to your comment, I tried that by setting it to 500x500 and it did not correct the issue, it still overwrote the webpage with the excel sheet, but only in the corner.

Comment: That had to happen, because html places objects in the top left by default. You can use the iframe within a div. The `position`, `padding` css can help you position it as well.